# Need assistance with JavaScript code to parse xml response

Tags: xml, api, httpresponse, mirth

Using Mirth Connect 3.7.1.  I have channel that uses destinations to:

1 destination - HTTP Sender to use a POST call to receive an 
authorization token.  Put the token into a variable to use in the next 
destination.

2 destination - HTTP Sender to use a GET call to receive an HTTP 
response in XML format.

3 destination - SQL writer uses the #2 destinations response, parses, 
maps parsed data, writes to a database.

I am having issues with 3destination...  or could be between 2 & 
3.... also, make note, I am new to all coding.  But Mirth is JavaScript 
friendly, so that is what is going to be used here.  All standard, no 
custom libraries or anything of the sort.

I receive the the response from 2destination and all the data I need is located in 
one spot of the XML...  ...  to make matters worse, 
there is repeating sets of data each set contained within curly brackets 
{name, location, credit}, {name, location, credit}, {name, location, 
credit} and so on...

The above inside the curly brackets is an example... not the actual 
parts.

I've looked at many forums and I believe it's very possible the answer is 
out there but being new to JS I could be having newbie issues making the 
syntax work for me...

I believe I have incorrectly used JSON.parse as well as incorrectly used 
parser = new DOMParser(); also incorrectly used xmlhttp.responseXML; etc 
etc...

***All in JavaScript*** ***GRB is Get Response Body (used as a variable 
to equal the portion of the XML where my data set is)***

```
/*
***result is DOMParser is not defined***
var GRB = msg['Body'].toString();
var GRBparser = new DOMParser();
var GRBDOM = GRBParser.parseFromString(GRB, "application/xml");
*/

/*
var GRB = msg['Body'].toString();
GRB = GRB.split('').forEach('{}');
*/

/*
var GRB = msg['Body'].toString().split('{}');
for each('{}') = i = 0; i++;
*/
```

***Again, I am new to this and looking for some help***

It would be ideal if the data would result in something like this =

nameF : John, 
nameL : Doe, 
location : University, 
date : 10/11/2019,

nameF : Sara, 
nameL: Conner, 
location : Pixie Land, 
date : 10/12/2019,

instead I get the following below ***It's the part at  that gives me the problem, all the data is there, I am 
replacing the actual data with fictitious data because HIPPA=

```
<HttpResponse><Status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</Status><Header><Field> 
<Name>Server</Name><Value>Microsoft-IIS/10.0</Value></Field><Field> 
<Name>X-Content-Type-Options</Name><Value>nosniff</Value></Field><Field> 
<Name>Connection</Name><Value>keep-alive</Value></Field><Field> 
<Name>Pragma</Name><Value>no-cache</Value></Field><Field><Name>X- 
Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies</Name><Value>none</Value></Field><Field> 
<Name>Date</Name><Value>Mon, 14 Oct 2019 18:18:49 GMT</Value></Field> 
<Field><Name>Strict-Transport-Security</Name><Value>max- 
age=31536000</Value></Field><Field><Name>Cache-Control</Name><Value>no- 
cache</Value></Field><Field><Name>Content-Security-Policy</Name> 
<Value>default-src https: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'</Value></Field> 
<Field><Name>X-AspNet-Version</Name><Value>4.0.30319</Value></Field> 
<Field><Name>Vary</Name><Value>Accept-Encoding</Value></Field><Field> 
<Name>Expires</Name><Value>-1</Value></Field><Field><Name>Content- 
Type</Name><Value>application/json; charset=utf-8</Value></Field> 
</Header> 
<Body multipart="no">[{"nameF": "John", "nameL": "Doe", "location": 
"University", "date": "10/11/2019"}, {"nameF": "Sara", "nameL": "Conner", 
"location": "Pixie Land", "date": "10/12/2019"}</Body></HttpResponse
```

Answer (score 0):

The following below worked.

```
//GRB = Get Response Body
//Parse GRB = PGRB
//sql_outs = data destined for sql db
var GRB = msg['Body'].toString();
var PGRB = JSON.parse(GRB);
channelMap.put('PGRB', PGRB);

var PGRB_length = PGRB.length;
var sql_outs = "";
sql_outs = sql_outs.concat("
```

(",PGRB[0].Credit,",",PGRB[0].StartDate,",",PGRB[0].EndDate,",",PGRB[0].IsStruck,",",PGRB[0].Notes,",",PGRB[0].StaffAbbrev,",",PGRB[0].StaffFName,",",PGRB[0].StaffId,",",PGRB[0].StaffLName,",",PGRB[0].TaskAbbrev,",",PGRB[0].TaskId,",",PGRB[0].TaskName,",",PGRB[0].EndTime,",",PGRB[0].StaffNpi,",",PGRB[0].StartTime,",",PGRB[0].TaskTags);

for (var i = 1; i

channelMap.put('sql_outs', sql_outs);

Comment: The formatting for stack overflow forced something wonky...  so it looks messed up.  But the entire portion above works.